# [PHP CURL]How to gat data from url with variable?

Tags: php, curl

Sry for english.
I have problem with this code:

```
$rezultat=$polaczenie->query("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 0,1");
$rezultat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat);
$rezultat=$rezultat['name'];
$connector = curl_init();
$steam='https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/$rezultat';
$steam=str_replace('$rezultat',$rezultat,$steam);
echo $steam;
curl_setopt($connector, CURLOPT_URL, $steam);
curl_setopt($connector, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($connector, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$out = curl_exec($connector);
echo "<!--".$out."-->";
curl_close($connector);
```

$rezultat is "Gamma 2 Case", $polaczenie is object from mysqli, $connector curl object, when I replace this line:

```
curl_setopt($connector, CURLOPT_URL, $steam);
```

to this:

```
curl_setopt($connector, CURLOPT_URL,"https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Gamma 2 Case"
```

everything is good. What I must do?
PS
When I try with first code this return "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Gamma 2 Case <!---->"

Comment: what do you see at `echo $steam;`

Comment: if echo gives you link with this '<!---->' thing, maybe you should simply try to cut it off, so that $steam would return a proper link.

Comment: @lawstud I think that is the second echo

Comment: no, <!----> is from this echo "<!--".$out."-->"; :)

Comment: @JKluseczka is there a " " at the end of `$steam`? You could try to use `urlencode()` on `$resultat`...

Comment: ok wait im testing

Comment: This working, but the out url is https://steam...Gamma+2+Case and steam not working :D but i do this: "$rezultat=str_replace("+","%20",$rezultat);" and this "$rezultat=str_replace("%0D","",$rezultat);" and this working thx a lot

Comment: wait, then you need `rawurlencode()` that will encode " " to "%20" and not "+"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `rawurlencode()` to encode " " in the last part of the URL. Use it on `$resultat`:

```
$rezultat=rawurlencode($rezultat['name']);
```